# Converting 0-3.3 V to 0-12 V

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc-dc-converter, fan, step-up, teensy

My Teensy 3.6 microcontroller outputs an analog 0 V - 3.3 V signal.

I plan to use my Teensy's PWM pin to control the speed of a fan that has 12 V as its 100%.

I wish to convert the 0 - 3.3V --> 0 - 12V.

What is the best way to achieve this? Should I buy a company-made buck converter? Maybe an op-amp circuit? If yes, which kind of op-amp? Will this simple transistor circuit do just fine?

[image: Simulation of the Transistor Circuit]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142017/discussion-on-question-by-megahgan-converting-0-3-3-v-to-0-12-v).

Answer (score 3):

With that much of a current requirement, the only practical way to do this is by PWM. Get yourself a "logic level" MOSFET (i.e a MOSFET that will be 100% "on" at 3.3V gate voltage. An "N-channel" that can handle at least 10A would be adequate. You probably won't even need a heatsink, or maybe just a small one.  Add a 10-100 resistor from PWM pin to gate, and another 10k gate to ground.
Also put a snubbing diode across the fan to quench voltage spikes.   A small capacitor across the fan can also help to prevent EMI  (e.g. 0.1uF ceramic or similar would be a reasonable starting point)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6cTid.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I couldn't find a symbol for a fan so I used a light bulb instead.
R1 prevents ringing.  R2 ensures the MOSFET turns completely off when you want it to.

Comment: In general I agree, but I got 2 questions regarding your circuit:
1: why is your IC PWM pin directly tied to GND? Doesnt that completely short your Signal to GND?
2: I believe you should put R1 between R2 and the Gate of M1 and not between R2 and the PWM pin. Right now R1 and R2 form a voltage divider and only 0-1.65V will get to M1's gate - at least to my understanding.

Comment: @PatrickFiedler i tried to simulate the circuit on proteus and you were right. it gives out 1.6ishV and if i put the R1 between the R2 and M1, it gives out 3.3V and the Fan turned on.

Comment: Also Thank you so much for the help! I am now trying to figure out the snubbing diode and the capacitor value.

Comment: This answer really needs to be fixed up... Firstly, the short circuit of the IC_PWM_PIN needs to be removed, but also R1's value needs to be substantially reduced.  A voltage divider at the gate is not what is needed - rather, R2 is a pull down, and R1 is to limit peak current (if the GPIO pins need thar favour) or avoid ringing

Comment: @megahgan perfect. I wasnt able to simulate it at the moment, so thank you for doing that and reporting back. Glad it works now!

Comment: @DanielChisholm I just proposed an edit where I switched the resistors around, changed R1 to 10 Ohms (which I believe to be more sensible) and removed the short. Someone with more trust has to approve it though.

Comment: @PatrickFiedler I agree that R1 should be around 10 ... 100 Ohms. But you should've modified the text as well, as it references two 10k resistors.

Comment: To all - Yeah I drew the resistors backwards LOL... Thx for fixing.   That's what I get for posting at 3AM   ;)   The short was probably a graphical typo...   I really don't remember doing that